# Find value in range of strings and return row number

Tags: excel, string, vba, find

Probably a easy question, but I've been stuck on this for days and can't find anyone with a similar problem, except when the values are in different cells.

```
A:Country   B:Zipcode
Denmark     3700 3701 3705 3708 3805 3902
France      17191 17193 17198
Germany     15760 15878 15985
```

For example:

```
Denmark & 3700 - return row 2. 
Denmark & 17191 - no match. 
France & 17191 - return row 3.
```

I have tried several solutions with FIND's, SUMIF's, SOMPRODUCT etc., but none is able to retrieve the row when all the zipcodes are in one cell.

I am able to retrieve whether the zipcodes exists in the entire column B, but not in which cell it finds a match.

Comment: What's the maximum number of zip codes you'd ever have in a cell?

Comment: @Bathsheba Up to a few thousand

Comment: Sounds like a VBA function to me then, based on the `Split` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2,$A$1:$A$4,1))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,$A$1:$A$4,1)),0),"No match")
```

Entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Formula]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tested this method and it works! However my data is separated in 2 different columns, so the method provided by @sktneer is more suiteable for me.

Comment: If it is two columns simply change range for the second search e.g. to B1:B4 where ever you have to pick the other values up from.  That should work.

Comment: Works perfectly. The other solution by @sktneer had a weird issue where cells with a large textstring weren't working, but this one works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: One small issue though: it also return true if only the zipcode is found as partial zipcode. For example: 7191 in the above zipcodes for France will return true, eventhough the exact match should be 17191. I will try to find a work-around for this.

Comment: You could add a Len test to ensure zipcode is same length

Comment: That's what I was also thinking, I think I got it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the data is setup as per the image below, you may try something like this...

In F2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ROW($A$2:$A$4),MATCH(D2&"*"&E2&"*",INDEX($A$2:$A$4&$B$2:$B$4,),0)),"No Match")
```

[image]

Comment: Although this is the correction solution and I can get it working with the dataset I provided, for some reason it does not work for large data sets (>100's of zipcodes in the cell), but can't figure out why.

Comment: It should work with any data set provided the layout is the same. :)

Comment: For some reason, when the length of the string in the zipcode column is longer than 245 characters, the formula stops working. Is this the same for you?